How to retain bits on lowp float when using `imageLoad` and `imageStore`
I would like to use all 8-bits as flags on a lowp float stored in an image. However, for some reason the data is never retained when I read it back. I use uintBitsToFloat and floatBitsToUint like so.
(Note: the format of output_image is r8_snorm. I cannot use int/uint image formats due to platform limitations.)
uint my_value = 123u;
imageStore(output_image, vec2(100, 100), vec4(uintBitsToFloat(my_value), 0.0, 0.0, 1.0));

// some different shader...

uint my_value = floatBitsToUint(imageLoad(output_image, vec2(100, 100)).r);
// uint equals some value greater than 0, but is not 123
// I have no idea how to figure out what value it is

If I just input an 8-bit compatible float value (like 12.0) it gets read back just fine, so I can only assume it has something to do with the storage process.
I'm assume this is because the lowp float is being converted to highp float at some point when it gets stored, and it gets converted back to a different value when I read it back? Is there any method to avoid this and achieve the behavior I'm hoping for?

lowp float and highp float are not really a thing. To the extent that there is any difference between these, it's implementation specific. Are you talking about 8-bit normalized integers (r8_snorm) vs. 32-bit floats? Because that's not what uintBitsToFloat is doing.

"I cannot use int/uint image formats due to platform limitations." What platform limitations? OpenGL 4.2 (which introduces image load/store) requires implementations to support integer textures. So if you have access to imageLoad/Store, then you can use r8i. Or are you using OpenGL ES of some version?

@NicolBolas Sorry for the delayed response. The anywhere I talk about lowp vs highp is just speculation on my part, the whole reason I'm asking this question is to learn why this doesn't work and it's the only thing I can think of. All I would like to do is reliably store an 8-bit uint in my r8 texture. uintBitsToFloat just retains the bits, right? If I run floatBitsToUint(uintBitsToFloat(123u)) I get 123u... yet if I do that through imageStore/imageLoad it doesn't work anymore, why?

@NicolBolas Sorry the platform limitation was a fib because the real reason is more complicated and I didn't want to distract from the question. The real reason is because Godot doesn't support it in its Texture2DRD resource. Trying to use r8ui results in "Unsupported image format" from TextureStorage::_texture_format_from_rd in texture_storage.cpp in the engine source code. I assume this is to retain compatibility, but that is not applicable to me. I am using the Vulkan Forward renderer.
